# MS ACCESS VBA 101: Get Cell Info From Table

Tags: ms-access, get, cell, record

Could somebody please help me get the cell info from an Access table with the use of VBA?

I have a table with 8 columns and 325 rows (records). I need my VBA code to be able to access a value in one of the fields depending on the row.

Basically, if I'm in row 20 I want to get the value in Column 2 of row 20. If I'm in row 33 I want to get the value in Column 2 of row 33.

I've tried the DLookup function but I can't get it to recognize which row I'm in.

I think this is an extremely basic procedure, yet I've struggled to find anything that addresses it on the web. I can do this with one line of code in Excel but Access is such a chore for me to learn. And I need to be able to do this in Access.

Could somebody please help me write code that will read the value of a cell in an MS Access Table?

Also, what's a good place for Access VBA Beginners?

Thanks,

Elias

Comment: [Here](http://functionx.com/access2007/Lesson01.htm) is a good place to learn about using Access with VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the link. 33 Pages on Microsoft Access. 0 Pages on Access VBA. No table of contents or index page. Just 33 pages on MS Access without VBA. Great resource nonetheless.

Comment: You are right.  Sorry about that.  [Here is the link I wanted](http://functionx.com/vbaccess/index.htm)